# Why 7 dB power increase after combining identical strength signals?

Tags: rf, microwave, ham-radio, power-meter

I have signals from two transmitters that are combined via a power combiner ([link](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/ZFSC-4-1+.pdf)).

Both signals are at 7 dBm when fed into the combiner on their own. When combining both, the meter either reads 7 dBm (one transmitter is sending) or 14 dBm (both are sending). However, in theory, I would expect only a 3 dB increase in signal strength (doubling the signal in dB.) I checked this behaviour with several meters and probes.

What could be the reason for an increase in 7 dB after combining two signals?

[image: Spectrum Analyser of combined signals (both transmitter are sending)]

Spectrum analyser of combined signals (both transmitter are sending.)

Comment: Is it possible your scope has the option to set units (dB) on the Y axis, but it's just a label? I.e. it doesn't actually make the scale logarithmic? Mine does. I can set Amps, Voltages or Milivolts, no conversion is done.

Comment: I would agree, that this is what it feels like. However, the values are actually measured in dB.

Comment: Just a guess, since you are doing a spectrum analysis maybe they are not perfectly in phase and there is some interference so it adds on one frequency and it subtract on another? It's one of the reason for using power meters and not analyzers in the first place

Comment: I measured with Keysight P-Series Power Meter and Keysight Vector Network Analyzer, shouldn't at least one of them picked up on this?

Comment: When you tested the case of only one transmitter, was the unused combiner port properly terminated?

Comment: For that matter, do your transmitters have 50 ohm output impedance at frequencies outside their output band?

Comment: The unused ports were terminated with 50 ohm terminators. I do not know/measure the impedance of the transmitter at other frequencies than 430-440 MHz yet (Transmitters were signalling at 434 and 435 MHz; there output impedance is 50 Ohm).

Comment: Maybe put a 6dB pad (or whatever you have) in series with a transmitter and see if the change reads what you expect?